# Uploading Images and showing its thumbnails accordingly in gridview

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, image

I want a functionality to start with where, I want to give user functionality of uploading images and the thumbnail should get display in the gridview with

1. Image titles
2. Image path
3. Image desc

All this data should also get stored in the table. I have created the table. Just need help from the codebehind.

Any help would be great.!!

Comment: whats your table structure?

Comment: @صفي: What do u want, I have `Id`,`image_id`,`image_desc`,`image_path`. All ids are `int` and others are `varchar` datatypes

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3bees.com/2013/03/resize-image-while-upload-using-php.html

try following the guide here sir, hope this helps. although its php. you can still convert the code.
in the tutorial it shows how the picture is resized and can be called.